# Ошибка при построении динамического JSON

Tags: jquery, json

Мне нужно кодом создавать динамический JSON массив, но в моем примере ошибка, что я упустил? код пишу с нуля в примеры не смотрел, обучаюсь:

> Не удалось получить свойство "call" ссылки, значение которой не определено или является NULL

```
var json = [];
var start = ['8/12/2018','8/14/2018']; 
var end = ['8/16/2018','8/20/2018'];
function createJson() {
  $.each(function(start,end){
    json.push({
      start: start,
      end: end
    })
  });
  return console.log(json);
}
createJson();
```

На выходе мне нужен такой результат:

```
json = [{
    "start": "8/12/2018",
    "end": "8/16/2018"
     }, {
    "start": "8/14/2018",
    "end": "8/20/2018"
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе если массивы одной длины можно сделать так, опять же если вас правильно понял:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var json = [];
  var start = ['8/12/2018','8/14/2018']; 
  var end = ['8/16/2018','8/20/2018'];
  function createJson() {
    $.each(start, function(i){
      json.push({
        start: start[i],
        end: end[i]
      })
    });
    return console.log(json);
  }
  createJson();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, массив всегда одной длины.